# Normalizing numeric variable according to a factor in R

Tags: r, normalization

I'm trying to normalize a variable (using the minimum and maximum values) according to a second, variable (a factor).

It'll be clearer using the `diamonds` dataframe as an example.

This normalizes the `carat` variable to the 0-1 interval:

```
di <- diamonds
di$caratn <- (di$carat-min(di$carat))/(max(di$carat)-min(di$carat))
```

But I would like to do the normalization according to the `clarity` variable (which is a factor). That is, taking all `carat` values of a given `clarity` and normalizing 0-1.

The result would be that the highest `carat` of `clarity` SI2 would have a value of 1, and the same thing for the other clarities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `ave()`:

```
di <- within(di,caratn <- ave(carat,clarity,FUN=function(x) (x-min(x))/diff(range(x))))
```

Comment: Perfect and simple! Thanks!